# Fuzzy `==`, or "almost_equal_to" function for strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I want to search for duplicates in my database, but it could be things like

"The smallest thing, and nothing more"
"The Smallest Things, And Nothing More"
"The smallest thing, and nothing more."
"The smallest thing, and nothing"

Is there an easy way to design a fuzzy `==` function that gives a weight of matching, instead of a binary true/false result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby ships with a library called `did_you_mean` it is used to make suggestions for code correction when you make a mistake like `"abc".downcsae` will ask you "Did you mean downcase?"

This library includes a module called `DidYouMean::Levenshtein` which has a method called `distance`. This distance is the number of transformations required for 2 strings to be equal
Example:

```
s = "The smallest thing, and nothing more" 
x = "The Smallest Things, And Nothing More"

DidYouMean::Levenshtein.distance(s,x)
#=> 6
DidYouMean::Levenshtein.distance(s.downcase,x.downcase)
#=> 1
```

This may be useful in your case although you would need to determine the threshold.

Implementation is also available via the [`Gem::Text`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Text.html#method-i-levenshtein_distance) module which you could include in a class if needed e.g.

```
class MyClass
  extend Gem::Text

  def self.fuzzy_equal?(x:, y:, threshold:3)
    levenshtein_distance(x,y) <= threshold
  end
end

MyClass.fuzzy_equal?(x: s,y: x)
#=> false
MyClass.fuzzy_equal?(x: s.downcase,y: x.downcase)
#=> true
MyClass.fuzzy_equal?(x: s,y: x, threshold: 10)
#=> true
```

Comment: This is incredible, thanks